# Fancybox Cancel Event

Tags: jquery, fancybox

With Fancybox, is there a way to associate an event with pressing the ESC key or clicking the close button? I need to be able to tell the difference between someone pressing escape and the a manual call to fancybox.close(). Basically, I have a series of popups that tie into a workflow and I need to know if the user cancelled the process in the middle. I looked at onClosed but that fires every time the instance is closed - regardless of the method.

I also looked at the onCancel event but that only seems to fire if you cancel while the instance is loading - not by pressing escape after it's loaded.

Thank you,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I would explore: Wite a function for fancybox's onStart callback that starts listening for a keypress event with keycode === 27 (escape key). In the onClose or onCleanup callback, remove the listener.

Comment: This is a fairly vague answer.  Some sample code would improve it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That was actually already in there, but there was no difference between hitting escape and the  "normal" close event. I've resolved this though... added a flag to be able to distinguish escape / close vs. the normal exit routine at the end of this particular process.

Thanks for your insight though - I appreciate the response!

Ryan